# Android Studio Chipmunk issue with Orientation for Preview

Tags: android, layout, orientation, preview

I have been using AS-Bumblebee for a couple of months with a new project. Recently I started adding landscape pages to the App. Clicking the Orientation for Preview button gave a dropdown list which included "Create Landscape Variation" which made the process easy.
Unfortunately, the SSD drive decided to die, forcing me to replace my Dev PC with a new one. When I installed Android Studio, it installed Chipmunk instead of Bumblebee. Now clicking the Orientation for Preview button only provides a dropdown list for Portrait, Landscape and UI Mode.

How can I get the other three dropdown options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to create landscape variant with the dropdown shown below in AS Chipmunk

[image]